# event.PageX, event.PageY

Tags: jquery, события

При перемещении курсора над элементом (подозреваю mousemove) требуется фиксировать два значения позиции курсора. Например по оси Х. Одно из них в настоящий момент, второе которое было, к примеру, 100 миллисекунд назад. Чтобы можно было их сравнить между собой.

Comment: Чудесно. Что не получается?

Answer (score 1):

Если над элементом, то решение очевидно:

```js
var oArea = document.querySelector('.area');
var nVectorX, nVectorY, tCheck, bCheck;
oArea.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  if (!bCheck) { nVectorX = event.offsetX; nVectorY = event.offsetY; bCheck = true; }
  if (!tCheck) {
    tCheck = setTimeout(function() {
      if (nVectorX > event.offsetX) {
        oArea.innerHTML = '  LEFT (';
      } else if (nVectorX < event.offsetX) {
        oArea.innerHTML = ' RIGHT (';
      } else {
        oArea.innerHTML = '     X (';
      }
      oArea.innerHTML += nVectorX + '_' + event.offsetX + ')  ';
      if (nVectorY > event.offsetY) {
        oArea.innerHTML += '  UP (';
      } else if (nVectorY < event.offsetY) {
        oArea.innerHTML += 'DOWN (';
      } else {
        oArea.innerHTML += '   Y (';
      }
      oArea.innerHTML += nVectorY + '_' + event.offsetY + ')';
      if (nVectorY == event.offsetY && nVectorX == event.offsetX) {
        oArea.innerHTML = 'STOP';
        clearTimeout(tCheck);
      }
      nVectorX = event.offsetX;
      nVectorY = event.offsetY;
      tCheck = null;
    }, 100);
  }
});
```

```css
.area {
  width: 400px;
  height: 180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: crosshair;
  border: 1px solid #090;
}
```

```html
<pre class="area"></pre>
```

PS Извиняюсь, что не jQuery - ну, не люблю я его))